# Prove that $\det V(1,2,..,n)$ divides $\det V(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)$, where each $V$ is the associated Vandermonde matrix

Tags: matrices, number-theory, determinant

> Let $k_1<k_2<...<k_n$ be integer numbers. Prove that $$\det\big(V_n(1,2,..,n)\big)\mid \det\big(V_n(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)\big),$$ where V is a Vandermonde matrix.

I think it is a generalization of an easy problem:
$$12\mid(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(d-c),$$ 
and it's harder. I have no idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $(x)_k = x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1)$ and consider the determinant
$$
D = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1&\dots &1\\
{k_1\choose 1} & {k_2\choose 1}&\dots &{k_n\choose 1}\\
{k_1\choose 2} & {k_2\choose 2}&\dots &{k_n\choose 2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\
{k_1\choose n-1} & {k_2\choose n-1}&\dots &{k_n\choose n-1}
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Clearly, 
$$
D = \frac{1}{\det V_n(1,2,\dots,n)}\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1&\dots &1\\
(k_1)_1 & (k_2)_1&\dots &(k_n)_1\\
(k_1)_2 & (k_2)_2&\dots &(k_n)_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\
(k_1)_{n-1} & (k_2)_{n-1}&\dots &(k_n)_{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
But the last determinant is easily transformed to $\det V_n(k_1,\dots,k_n)$ with the help of row operations.

It would be nice to see a combinatorial interpretation of $D$.